# Find the probability that the letter came from MAHARASTRA

Tags: probability

A mail is known to have come from **MAHARASTRA**or **MADRAS**. On the post mark only consecutive letters **RA** can be read clearly. What is the chance that the mail came from MAHARASTRA? 
Please assume that equal number of mails per year are posted from Maharastra and Madras.

My try:-

As the number of RA in MAHARASTRA is 2 and in Madras is 1, the chance is 2/3.
But I think the answer is incorrect. Please help me to identify my mistake.

Comment: Just to clarify. There is 1 mail you received. All the letters no the front of the mail are omitted expect for **RA**. We want to know the probability the letter came from which city?

Comment: Tony Hellmuth sir. So that's why I found that there is a mistake. But I solved the same problem using Bayers' theorem and got the correct answer. But my question is why this logic is incorrect.

Comment: I believe your answer is correct and trivial. People are getting confused by your question, because you say letter and letters with 2 completely different meanings!

Comment: Ok sir I will edit the question so that people don't get confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I can explain your mistake - on the assumption that in a mangled postmark the pair of visible letters is chosen uniformly from all the pairs.

Here is an analogy that might help. Imagine two bags, one with $1000$ blue marbles and $2$ red marbles, one with $1$ blue marble and $1$ red marble. Someone says they picked a bag at random and then a marble at random and it was red. Which bag is more likely? Can you see intuitively why the probability that it was the second bag is quite large, and not just the $1/3$ you get by looking only at the three red marbles?

To get the precise probability you use Bayes' theorem, as in the answer from @ab123 .

Answer (score 2):

The question cannot be answered without further information. What is the volume of post from Maharashtra compared to Madras? For example, if only one letter per year comes from Maharashtra, and ten million letters come from Madras, then chances are that it's from Madras.

Also, Maharashtra is a state while Madras is a city, so depending on the format of post marks, we might be able to deduce the answer right away (e.g., if the typeface is larger for states than for cities, or if the position is an indication).

Finally, note that Madras was officially renamed Chennai in 1996, so if the letter was sent within the past 20 years, chances are it's from Maharashtra.

Comment: It says "a letter"?  Like 1. It also says "the letter".

Comment: @TonyHellmuth There are two kinds of letters in the question: letters in the mail, and letters in the alphabet. Also, 1 is not a letter.

Comment: I am so confused. 1 letter came. But now there are 2 letters. OMG hahahaha

Comment: Théophe sir. Please assume that equal number of letters per year are posted from Maharastra and Madras.

Comment: In questions like these it's typical to assume that the distribution is uniform unless otherwise specified. (Coins and dice are assumed to be fair; decks are assumed to have been thoroughly shuffled.)

Comment: Don't downmark it, the question is confusing with letters being mentioned in 2 completely different contexts...

Comment: Sir I have edited the question

Comment: @MeesdeVries Cities are not dice!

Comment: I agree with you that problems posed as if they were real deserve real answers. You make your point by treating it as if it were real and not just one of those all too common fake "word problems" constructed to test the understanding of some more abstract piece of mathematics. It should just have been asked about balls and urns.

Answer (score 2):

By Bayes' theorem,

$P$(letter from Maharashtra|we see 'RA') = $\frac{P(RA| Maha)P(Maha)}{P(RA| Maha)P(Maha) + P(RA|Mad)P(Mad)}$

and use $P(Maha) = P(Mad)$

Comment: I have done the same way and got the answer but why my logic is incorrect,ab123 sir.

Answer (score 0):

E1:  Letter (RA) came from MADRAS

E2 :  Letter (RA) came from MAHARASHTRA

E : Event that 2 consecutive times the letter (RA) is visible.

P(E1) = P(E2) = 1/2

MADRAS can be broken down to : MA,AD,DR,RA,AS = 5 pairs in which ONE pair contains letter RA .
Therefore,
$P(\frac{\text{Number of times RA is present}}{\text{letter came from MADRAS}}) = P(\frac{E}{_{E1}}) = \frac{1}{5}$

MAHARASHTRA can be broken down to : MA,AH,HA,AR,RA,AS,SH,HT,TR,RA = 10 pairs in which TWO pairs cRAtain the letter RA .

$P(\frac{\text{Number of times RA is present}}{\text{letter came from MAHARASHTRA}}) = P(\frac{E}{_{E2}}) = \frac{2}{10}$

Then the Probability that the letter RA came from MAHARASHTRA when Just 2 consecutive letter(RA) are visible is given  = $P(\frac{E2}{E}) = \frac{P(E2) * P(\frac{E}{E2})}{{P(E2) * P(\frac{E}{E2}) + P(E1) * P(\frac{E}{E1})}} = \frac{\frac{1}{2} * \frac{2}{10}}{\frac{1}{2} * [ \frac{2}{10} + \frac{1}{5}]} $